# Desktop gadget (sidebar) birthday reminder

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, desktop-gadget

Does anyone knows a desktop gadget (win vista or 7) that reads and displays events (birthdays) from yahoo/hotmail calendar??

I used a Yahoo Widget for in win XP but now I want to use a sidebar gadget...

Answer (score 1):

This widget would have to be specificity made by yahoo since they have a proprietary calendar system.  You would have a much better chance by exporting your calendar to a windows format and using a regular calendar gadget.